# mysql subquery using union vs left join?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to optimize my sql subquery.

this is the old version of my sql query using `UNION` and selecting the fields in subqueries:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            t7.*, '7' AS priority
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    `mytable`.`id`,
                    `mytable`.`title`,
                    `mytable`.`cover_photo`,
                    `mytable`.`city_id`,
                    `mytable`.`city_name`,
                    `cities`.`name` AS `master_city_name`,
                    `mytable`.`state_id`,
                    `mytable`.`state_name`,
                    `states`.`name` AS `master_state_name`,
                    `countries`.`id` AS `country_id`,
                    `countries`.`name` AS `country_name`
                FROM
                    `mytable`
                LEFT JOIN `cities` ON `cities`.`id` = `mytable`.`city_id`
                LEFT JOIN `states` ON `states`.`id` = `mytable`.`state_id`
                LEFT JOIN `countries` ON `countries`.`id` = `mytable`.`country_id`
                JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `mytable`.`user_id`
                WHERE
                    `mytable`.`status` = 'published'
                AND `mytable`.`city_id` = '161'
            ) AS t7
        UNION
            SELECT
                t8.*, '8' AS priority
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT
                        `mytable`.`id`,
                        `mytable`.`title`,
                        `mytable`.`cover_photo`,
                        `mytable`.`city_id`,
                        `mytable`.`city_name`,
                        `cities`.`name` AS `master_city_name`,
                        `mytable`.`state_id`,
                        `mytable`.`state_name`,
                        `states`.`name` AS `master_state_name`,
                        `countries`.`id` AS `country_id`,
                        `countries`.`name` AS `country_name`
                    FROM
                        `mytable`
                    LEFT JOIN `cities` ON `cities`.`id` = `mytable`.`city_id`
                    LEFT JOIN `states` ON `states`.`id` = `mytable`.`state_id`
                    LEFT JOIN `countries` ON `countries`.`id` = `mytable`.`country_id`
                    JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `mytable`.`user_id`
                    WHERE
                        `mytable`.`status` = 'published'
                    AND `mytable`.`state_id` = '12'
                ) AS t8
            UNION
                SELECT
                    t9.*, '9' AS priority
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT
                            `mytable`.`id`,
                            `mytable`.`title`,
                            `mytable`.`cover_photo`,
                            `mytable`.`city_id`,
                            `mytable`.`city_name`,
                            `cities`.`name` AS `master_city_name`,
                            `mytable`.`state_id`,
                            `mytable`.`state_name`,
                            `states`.`name` AS `master_state_name`,
                            `countries`.`id` AS `country_id`,
                            `countries`.`name` AS `country_name`
                        FROM
                            `mytable`
                        LEFT JOIN `cities` ON `cities`.`id` = `mytable`.`city_id`
                        LEFT JOIN `states` ON `states`.`id` = `mytable`.`state_id`
                        LEFT JOIN `countries` ON `countries`.`id` = `mytable`.`country_id`
                        JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `mytable`.`user_id`
                        WHERE
                            `mytable`.`status` = 'published'
                        AND `mytable`.`country_id` = '64'
                    ) AS t9
    ) AS t
ORDER BY
    `t`.`priority`,
    RAND()
LIMIT 25
```

and after doing some research, this is the new one I've come up with using the supposedly better `LEFT JOIN` and selecting the fields in the main query:

```sql
SELECT
    `mytable`.`id`,
    `mytable`.`title`,
    `mytable`.`cover_photo`,
    `mytable`.`city_id`,
    `mytable`.`city_name`,
    `cities`.`name` AS `master_city_name`,
    `mytable`.`state_id`,
    `mytable`.`state_name`,
    `states`.`name` AS `master_state_name`,
    `countries`.`id` AS `country_id`,
    `countries`.`name` AS `country_name`,
    subquery.priority
FROM mytable
left join cities on cities.id = mytable.city_id
left join states on states.id = mytable.state_id
left join countries on countries.id = mytable.country_id
left join users on users.id = mytable.user_id
left join
(
    SELECT
        `mytable`.`id`, '7' as priority
    FROM
        `mytable`
    LEFT JOIN `cities` ON `cities`.`id` = `mytable`.`city_id`
    WHERE
        `mytable`.`city_id` = '161'
    UNION
    SELECT
        `mytable`.`id`, '8' as priority
    FROM
        `mytable`
    LEFT JOIN `states` ON `states`.`id` = `mytable`.`state_id`
    WHERE
        `mytable`.`state_id` = '12'
    UNION
    SELECT
        `mytable`.`id`, '9' as priority
    FROM
        `mytable`
    LEFT JOIN `countries` ON `countries`.`id` = `mytable`.`country_id`
    WHERE
        `mytable`.`country_id` = '64'
) AS subquery on subquery.id = mytable.id
where users.active = 1 and subquery.priority is not NULL
ORDER BY
    `subquery`.`priority`,
    RAND()
LIMIT 25
```

which one is more preferable performance-wise?

Comment: How long does it take to get a result for each query?

Comment: it was less than 0.5 second in a 100+ table rows (single user, single table, on development server). but in production, there will be thousands of rows on several tables and multiple users accessing this process at the same time.

Comment: Does both query return the same results?

Comment: yes. they both return the same results. but nevermind, I've got my answer. before, I didn't see the exact Query Time shown by my software.. and it turns out, the first one takes > 0.030s and the second one takes around 0.020s. thanks for your time though